# Kubernetes PersistentVolume data is lost after physical machine restart

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage

I recently started using PersistentVolumes and PersistenVolumeClaims for persistent storage in my container.

My end goal is to make sure that a file in a specific folder (let's call it `data`) on the container survives any restart.
The implementation is:

1. Creation of the PersistentVolume
2. Creation of the PersistentVolumeClaim that automatically binds to the PV thanks to a Storage Class
3. Creation of a simple deployment that pulls a single image from a remote repository

The deployment starts correctly. I am able to connect to the only container and create a file in `data`

If i delete and recreate the deployment, i can see that it pulls the image, recreates the pod and the container, and by reconnecting to the container i see the file previously created in the folder `data`. This is expected behaviour.

If i restart my PC, I can see the deployment automatically starting the pods, and both the PV and PVC are still there and working.

However, if I access the `data` folder, i can't see the previously created file. So, my questions are:

**1. Are PersistentVolumes meant to persist even after a hard machine restart?**

**2. If so, how can I achieve this?**

I understand that I am missing a lot of theory on how Kubernetes works, but the official documentation doesn't cover this, and I couldn't find any useful information online.
If you need any YAML file of the entities just tell me. Thanks.

EDIT:

Yaml config of both the PV and PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: vl0001
    spec:
      storageClassName: my-sc
      capacity:
        storage: 2Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      local:
        path: /mnt
      nodeAffinity:
        required:
          nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
              - node0001
```

PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc0001
spec:
  storageClassName: my-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: How are you testing Kubernetes? You mentioned your computer, does that mean you are using minikube?

Comment: @AndD no, I'm not using minikube. I only Installed Docker desktop and then enabled Kubernetes by the settings page

Comment: What kind of persistent volumes are you trying to create? Host path? Can you post the yaml definition?

Comment: added both PV and PVC YAML to the question

Comment: I'm unable to test Docker Desktop but searching around I found this which mees related: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023

Comment: That's exactly the problem I am facing. Looks like it's on the Docker side but they did't event address the issue...

Comment: @Axel you solved?

Comment: Not yet, but I haven't tried in a while. I'll test this again on the latest Docker Desktop version asap and update this post.

Comment: Any update to this issue?  Seeing the same problem.

Comment: No update by me. We decided to not use persistent volumes as they simply don't work.